# UI equivalent of setFrameCenterRotation?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, rotation

I have been coding for MacOs for months and now exploring iOS. It's a bit confusing.

In MacOS, I have a NSImageView I can rotate using setFrameCenterRotation. One outlet, one call, and the work is done.

I suppose there is an equivalent in iOS but I could only find code examples using animation and a lot of calculation (certainly to make "nice" game-like features on this tiny screen).

I don't want any animation, just my ...UIImageView to rotate in one block from a given number of degrees.

Can it be done?

Any suggestion really welcome!

Regards,
B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want to set the view's `transform` property to a rotation transform.  Example:

```
CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI / 180;
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

`UIImageView` inherits the `transform` property from `UIView`, so you will need to consult the [*UIView Class Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW4) for documentation.

Comment: Thank you Rob, it works perfectly. Finally, I have the same number of code lines… what a relief.